# Class method ios what does "self" refer to

Tags: objective-c, singleton

```
#import "ApiService.h"

@implementation ApiService
static ApiService *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (ApiService *)sharedInstance
{
    if (sharedInstance == nil)
    {
        sharedInstance =  [[self alloc]init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

When I call `+sharedInstance` what does self refer to? How am I allowed to call init from a Class method?

Comment: Check out this question for a better way to make a singleton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refering to the class itself from within a class mehod in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255237/refering-to-the-class-itself-from-within-a-class-mehod-in-objective-c)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassMethod.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is the class.

```
+ (id)create {
  return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

Is the same as:

```
+ (id)create {
  return [[SomeClass alloc] init];
}
```

Or in your example:

```
+ (ApiService *)sharedInstance
{
    if (sharedInstance == nil)
    {
        sharedInstance =  [[ApiService alloc]init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

This allows you to call class methods on `self` from class methods.  And it allows you to call them on the child class when you have inheritance, as class methods are inherited too.

Comment: If self is the class, then when you do things like: self.property, how can that be the class? unless the property is static?

Comment: @Rob, indeed there are 2 selfs in objective-c, check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassMethod.html

Comment: or better phrased: classes are objects themselves and as such they can send messages to themselves via `self`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773054/are-classes-objects-in-objective-c

Comment: looked at the link, that is strange, in C++ or Java, you certainly would not use this terminology, e.g. this is not the class...

Comment: because classes don't have properties, unless they are properties that apply to all instances.. ?

Comment: @Rob: properties is not the only use for self.

Comment: and there is nothing like static or class properties.

Comment: Self from a class method is the class, allowing you to call class methods. Self from an instance method is the instance allowing you to call instance methods.

Comment: It has practical reasons to use self in class methods. In a inheritance scenario, using "self" instead of  "ApiService" will guarantee that subclass of ApiService don't have to override "sharedInstance" method and be able to get the subclass object correctly. This trick is actually mentioned in Apple's programming guide https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html. At very bottom, Tip: Rather than using [[XYZPerson alloc] init] in the class factory method, instead try using [[self alloc] init].