# UIAlertView Delegate method not called in UITextView Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I'm tying to call `didDismissWithButtonIndex` on `UITextView` Class ,but it not called.
I also implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` on `MyViewcontroller.h` file and `[alert setDelegate:self]` to method.

*So is that possible to call `UIAlertView` Delegate method in `UITextView` Class ??*

```
+ (void)deleteTextr:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert  = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Delete Text !!!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
        [alert setDelegate:self];
        [alert show];
    }
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [self removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: try didDismissWithButtonIndex in clickedatbuttonindex

Comment: Non UIAlertView delegate method called in class.

Comment: Why is your `deleteTextr:` method a class method instead of an instance method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change delegate method to class method. like this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

// - change to +

```
+ (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Answer (score 2):

`deleteTextr:` is a class method. In the context of a class method, `self` is just a reference to the class. To use the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol, you need assign an instance of a class to the UIAlertView instance's delegate property, which can only be done within an instance method.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255237/refering-to-the-class-itself-from-within-a-class-mehod-in-objective-c) to get a better grasp of the aforementioned concept.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use `self` as a class reference as the delegate. It's not typical but it does work. Of course the delegate method needs to be a class method for it to work.